# why is this C union of strings function not working - segfault?

Tags: c, string, union, c99

This is a function to find union of strings.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>



char* my_union(char* param_1, char* param_2)
{
    char *res[strlen(param_1) + strlen(param_2)];  //allocate long enough string

    //check if the letter is in result res string 
    for(int i = 0 ; i < strlen(param_1);i++){
        if(strchr(*res,param_1[i]) == NULL){// this checks for duplicates
            res[i] = param_1[i];
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0 ; i < strlen(param_2);i++){
        if (strchr(*res, param_2[i])== NULL){//this checks for duplicates too
            *res[i] = param_2[i];
        }
    }

    printf("%s\n", *res);
    return *res;

}


int main(){
    char *s1 = "zpadinton" ;
    char *s2 =  "paqefwtdjetyiytjneytjoeyjnejeyj";
    my_union(s1,s2);// must return "zpadintoqefwjy"
   //the union is zpadintoqefwjy
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char *res[strlen(param_1) + strlen(param_2)];` --> `char res[strlen(param_1) + strlen(param_2) + 1];` without `*` (otherwise you end up with an array of pointers) and `+ 1` for the trailing `\0`, same for `if (strchr(*res`, remove the `*` but keep in mind that you are using `res` uninitialized, this is a mess, start the program again compiling with warnings.

Comment: Don't forget that you cannot use `res` outside of your function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> char *res[strlen(param_1) + strlen(param_2)];  //allocate long enough string

You cannot allocate dynamic length on stack. You need to allocate it on heap, like this:

`char *res = malloc(strlen(param_1) + strlen(param_2)+1);`

(Note: add an extra byte for the null terminator)

You need to set the buffer to zeros to be able to use strchr later:

`memset(res, 0, strlen(param_1) + strlen(param_2)+1);`

> if(strchr(*res,param_1[i]) == NULL){// this checks for duplicates
>              res[i] = param_1[i];
>          }

strchr should take `res`, not `*res`.
Assignment to index `i` would not work, as you need to add the new character at the end of the result string.

```
int j=0;
for(int i = 0 ; i < strlen(param_1);i++){
    if(strchr(res,param_1[i]) == NULL){// this checks for duplicates
        res[j] = param_1[i];
        j++;
    }
}

for(i = 0 ; i < strlen(param_2);i++){
    if (strchr(res, param_2[i])== NULL){//this checks for duplicates too
        res[j] = param_2[i];
        j++;
    }
}

printf("%s\n", res);
return res;
```

Comment: "You cannot allocate dynamic length on stack" Sure you can, but you can't return a pointer to that local array from the function.

Answer (score 3):

Some fundamental bugs:

- `char *res[]` is an array of pointers. You don't want that.
- `strlen(param_1) + strlen(param_2)` is not long enough, you didn't allocate space for the null terminator.
- `return *res;` returning a pointer to a local variable is always wrong, because that variable goes out of scope when the function returns.

  You either need to let the called do the allocation and write to one of the passed parameters, or you need to allocate memory for the string dynamically.

Notably, since you incorrectly used an array of pointers, stuff like `res[i] = param_1[i];` should not compile cleanly. You will get warnings "assignment from incompatible type"/"pointer from integer without a cast" or something like that.

Always read and correct warnings. For a beginner, a warning is pretty much 100% certain equal a bug. Crank up your warning level to the max and even better, block invalid code from compiling in the first place. For example gcc/clang/icc: `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -Werror`.